# About Node,Element,HTMLElement,Document,HTMLDocument,EventTarget

Tags: javascript, dom

I cannot understand what exactly the above names represent. MDN refers to them as `interfaces`. They seem to be neither `DOM nodes` since properties like **parentNode** and **nodeType** are not applied, nor javascript objects.

From the other hand, they appear to the prototype chain of DOM objects: e.g. `document-->HTMLDocument.prototype-->Document.prototype-->Node.prototype...` 
***So, what exactly are they?***

And for the end, something that will go me crazy. Let's take **HTMLElement.prototype**. It is that `HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('title')` is true. However `HTMLElement.prototype.title` returns **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)** in Chrome Developer Tools!! Is there any logical explanation for this paradox?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are objects (i.e. members of type Object). More specifically, host objects (i.e. supplied by the host environment).

There is no paradox.

For example, on all nodes you can access their `parentNode`. That property is not an own property of each node, it's inherited from `Node.prototype` instead. The property `Node.prototype.parentNode` is defined as an accessor property (getter/setter).

Then, when you do something like `document.body.parentNode`, the getter is called with `document.body` as the `this` value. However, when you use `Node.prototype.parentNode`, the getter receives `Node.prototype` as the `this` value, which is not a node. So it throws.

You can also call them "interfaces", because they are defined in W3C specs as [IDL interfaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-interfaces). For example, `Node` is defined in [the DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-node).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces, or prototype declarations.

For accessing a property of something, you need an instance.

In this case, an instance of HTMLElement.
Then you can query HTMLElement.title.

Note that in Javascript, objects and interfaces are actually functions, but not always to just be called.

Comment: You can get a "body" HTMLElement of the document by using `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`.